# how to extend linear and nonlinear trend line in R scatterplot

Tags: r, linear-regression, scatter-plot, non-linear-regression

I have two data sets from WDI, they are normalized GDP of USA and CHINA from 2000 to 2012.

```
WDICHN$Year <- c(2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012)
WDICHN$NormalizedGDP  <- c(1.20,1.32,1.45,1.64,1.93,2.25,2.71,3.50,4.52,5.00,5.93,7.32,8.23)

WDIUSA$Year <- c(2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012)
WDIUSA$NormalizedGDP  <- c(10.28,10.62,10.98,11.51,12.27,13.10,13.86,14.48,14.72,14.42,14.97,15.52,16.16)
```

I would like to create a scatter plot for both dataset and combine them together first. then I also want to add trend line and extend those lines to see approximately when they will meet each other.

I use the follow code:

```
scatterplot(NormalizedGDP~Year,smooth=FALSE, boxplots=FALSE,ylim=range(0,20),xlim=range(2000,2030),
   data=WDIUSA)
par(new=TRUE)
scatterplot(NormalizedGDP~Year,boxplots=FALSE,ylim=range(0,20),xlim=range(2000,2030),
   data=WDICHN)
```

this code plot all points and draw the fit lines but it did not extend the lines so I can not see when they will meet each other. can anyone helps me how to extend the lines so I can tell when they can meet approximately. Thanks a lot!

[image: Graph is here]

Comment: This required some digging. The function calls `car:::scatterplot.default`, which calls `loessLine` and `regLine`. Each of these functions are called using the values from your data (based on your formula here). Eg: There is no obvious way to change the call to `car::scatterplot` to extend the line. If you want to extend the line, you'd have to 1) create the scatterplot without lines, 2) estimate regression and smoother using `loess` and `lm`. 3) Generate data from the area you want to visualize. 4) Use the models to predict this data. 5) Add the lines to your data plot using the predictions.

Answer (score 1):

Answering based on my comment above. Looking at the documentation of `?car::scatterplot` and the underlying documentation, it is *not* possible to extend the lines automatically using the function. So this will have to be done manually. We can done this in 5 steps, outlined below:

## 1: create the scatterplot without lines

```
library(car)
WDICHN <- data.frame(Year = c(2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012),
                     NormalizedGDP = c(1.20,1.32,1.45,1.64,1.93,2.25,2.71,3.50,4.52,5.00,5.93,7.32,8.23))
WDIUSA <- data.frame(Year = c(2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012),
                     NormalizedGDP = c(10.28,10.62,10.98,11.51,12.27,13.10,13.86,14.48,14.72,14.42,14.97,15.52,16.16))
scatterplot(NormalizedGDP ~ Year, 
            smooth = FALSE, 
            boxplots = FALSE,
            ylim = range(0, 20),
            xlim = range(2000, 2030),
            data = WDIUSA)
par(new=TRUE)
scatterplot(NormalizedGDP ~ Year,
            boxplots = FALSE,
            ylim = range(0, 20),
            xlim = range(2000, 2030),
            data = WDICHN)
```

## 2: estimate regression and smoother using loess and lm

```
smoothers <- lapply(list(WDICHN, WDIUSA), 
                    function(x)lm(NormalizedGDP ~ Year, data = x))
regLines <- lapply(list(WDICHN, WDIUSA), 
                   function(x)loess(NormalizedGDP ~ Year, data = x))
```

## 3: Generate data from the area you want to visualize

```
predData <- data.frame(Year = seq(2000, 2030))
```

## 4: Use the models to predict this data

```
predData$USA_smooth <- predict(smoothers[[2]], newdata = predData)
predData$USA_regLine <- predict(regLines[[2]], newdata = predData)
predData$CHN_smooth <- predict(smoothers[[1]], newdata = predData)
predData$CHN_regLine <- predict(regLines[[1]], newdata = predData)
```

## 5: Add the lines to your data plot using the predictions

```
with(predData, {
  lines(Year, USA_smooth, col = 'blue')
  lines(Year, CHN_smooth, col = 'blue')
  lines(Year, USA_regLine, col = 'blue')
  lines(Year, CHN_regLine, col = 'blue')
})
```

## Result

Note in the result below that `loess` is a smoother, and thus does not predict data outside the data range. I simply included it for illustrations.
[image: result_plot]

Comment: `control = loess.control(surface = "direct")` will allow you to extrapolate.  The validity of such extrapolation is of course more than a little suspect.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example for just the China piece.

```r
WDICHN <- data.frame(Year = c(2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012),
NormalizedGDP  = c(1.20,1.32,1.45,1.64,1.93,2.25,2.71,3.50,4.52,5.00,5.93,7.32,8.23))
WDIUSA <- data.frame(Year = c(2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012),
NormalizedGDP  = c(10.28,10.62,10.98,11.51,12.27,13.10,13.86,14.48,14.72,14.42,14.97,15.52,16.16))


model_china <- loess(NormalizedGDP ~ Year, 
                     data = WDICHN, 
                     control = loess.control(surface = "direct"))

more_china <- data.frame(Year = 2000:2030)
more_china$NormalizedGDP <- predict(model_china, more_china, se = TRUE)$fit
more_china
#>    Year NormalizedGDP
#> 1  2000      1.222329
#> 2  2001      1.292441
#> 3  2002      1.429555
#> 4  2003      1.635012
#> 5  2004      1.899512
#> 6  2005      2.242152
#> 7  2006      2.796770
#> 8  2007      3.533362
#> 9  2008      4.301920
#> 10 2009      5.142493
#> 11 2010      6.094303
#> 12 2011      7.136082
#> 13 2012      8.281193
#> 14 2013      9.530239
#> 15 2014     10.880763
#> 16 2015     12.330610
#> 17 2016     13.877994
#> 18 2017     15.521507
#> 19 2018     17.260056
#> 20 2019     19.092792
#> 21 2020     21.019047
#> 22 2021     23.038296
#> 23 2022     25.150119
#> 24 2023     27.354177
#> 25 2024     29.650195
#> 26 2025     32.037947
#> 27 2026     34.517246
#> 28 2027     37.087937
#> 29 2028     39.749887
#> 30 2029     42.502987
#> 31 2030     45.347142
car::scatterplot(NormalizedGDP ~ Year, 
                 boxplots=FALSE, 
                 ylim=range(0,50), 
                 xlim=range(2000,2030),
                  data=more_china)
```

[image]

Comment: this extends the line, but does not include the existing data.